# redux thunk doesnt delete items from the API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

My app is a simple bookstore, I am using this API https://www.notion.so/Bookstore-API-51ea269061f849118c65c0a53e88a739 I am able to get the books and post books whitout problems, but when I delete the books it works in the UI but when I refresh the page the books just come back,so is not deleting the books from the API.

this is my reducer

```
const bookReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD:
      return [
        ...state, action.book,
      ];
    case REMOVE: 
    return state.filter((book) => book.item_id !== action.book.item_id);
    case FETCH_BOOKS: {
      const bookList = [];
      Object.entries(action.books).forEach(([key, value]) => bookList.push({
        item_id: key,
        title: value[0].title,
        author: value[0].author,
        category: value[0].category,
      }));
      return bookList;
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

and this is my actions for deleting the books :
first my remove action

```
export const removeBook = (book) => ({
  type: REMOVE,
  book,
});
```

and then my action using thunks

```
export const deleteBooks = createAsyncThunk(REMOVE, async (bookId, thunkAPI) => {
  const response = await fetch(`${BOOK_URL}/${bookId}`,  {
   method: 'DELETE',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      item_id: bookId
    }),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  });
  await thunkAPI.dispatch(removeBook(bookId));
  return response.data;
});
```

now here is the function where I call the deleteBooks

```
function Book({title, author, item_id, category}) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const deleteHandler = (id) =>{
    console.log(id);
    dispatch(deleteBooks(id))
  }
  return (
    <>
      <span>
        {title}
        </span>
        <br/>
        <span>
        {author}
      </span>
      <br/>
      <span>
        {category}
      </span>
      <br/>
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => deleteHandler({item_id})}
      >
        Remove
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

From what I can read of the code it appears at some point when initiating the process to remove a book you drop the correct id somewhere along the way.

1. User clicks "Remove" button and `deleteHandler` is called and `{ item_id }` value is passed.
2. `deleteHander` names argument `id`
3. `deleteHandler` dispatches the `deleteBooks` action with `{ item_id }` as argument, now named `bookId`

```
function Book({ title, author, item_id, category }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const deleteHandler = (id) => { // (2) id == { item_id }
    console.log(id);
    dispatch(deleteBooks(id)); // (3)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <span>
        {title}
        </span>
        <br/>
        <span>
        {author}
      </span>
      <br/>
      <span>
        {category}
      </span>
      <br/>
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => deleteHandler({ item_id })} // (1)
      >
        Remove
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

4. `deleteBooks` consumes `bookId` and passes it ***directly*** in the DELETE requests URL path, and in the request body

***It is at this point I'd expect the DELETE request to fail in the backend since the URL is likely incorrect and the body is incorrect.*** `fetch` only throws an error on network errors or cancelled requests though, so I am sure the code just continues along error-free. I'm fairly certain `response.data` is simply undefined.

5. `deleteBooks` dispatches `removeBook` and passes `bookId`, still `{ item_id }`, as a payload

```
export const deleteBooks = createAsyncThunk(
  REMOVE,
  async (bookId, thunkAPI) => {
    const response = await fetch(`${BOOK_URL}/${bookId}`,  { // (4)
      method: 'DELETE',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        item_id: bookId // (4) { item_id: { item_id } }
      }),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });
    await thunkAPI.dispatch(removeBook(bookId)); // (5)
    return response.data;
  }
);
```

6. `removeBook` takes `{ item_id }` as a payload value

```
export const removeBook = (book) => ({ // (6) { item_id }
  type: REMOVE,
  book, // (6) { item_id } -> action.book.item_id
});
```

7. `bookReducer` reducer function handles `REMOVE` action and correctly accesses into the action payload to get the nested `item_id` property and filters the book state array.

```
const bookReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    ...

    case REMOVE: 
      return state.filter((book) => book.item_id !== action.book.item_id); // (7)

    ...
  }
};
```

## Solution

Payload/argument naming issues aside, you can likely fix the issue in the `deleteBooks` action by correctly accessing into the passed "book" object to get the nested `item_id` property.

Example:

```
export const deleteBooks = createAsyncThunk(
  REMOVE,
  async (book, thunkAPI) => {
    const { item_id } = book // <-- destructure item_id from book object
    const response = await fetch(`${BOOK_URL}/${item_id}`,  { // <-- pass in URL path
     method: 'DELETE',
      body: JSON.stringify({ item_id }), // <-- pass in body
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });
    await thunkAPI.dispatch(removeBook(book)); // <-- pass book object
    return response.data;
  }
);
```

### Suggestions

#### Use consistent naming throughout code

I suggest editing all these functions/actions/reducers/etc to consistently name the referenced objects throughout the code. It's much easier to keep and maintain the mental mapping of the data flowing through/across the app.

Since the `Book` component starts with just a book id, i.e. the `item_id` prop, then passing a "book id" value around makes a bit more sense.

```
function Book({ title, author, item_id, category }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const deleteHandler = (id) => {
    console.log(id);
    dispatch(deleteBooks(id));
  }

  return (
    <>
      <span>
        {title}
        </span>
        <br/>
        <span>
        {author}
      </span>
      <br/>
      <span>
        {category}
      </span>
      <br/>
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => deleteHandler(item_id)} // <-- pass book id
      >
        Remove
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

```
export const deleteBooks = createAsyncThunk(
  REMOVE,
  async (bookId, thunkAPI) => {
    const response = await fetch(`${BOOK_URL}/${bookId}`,  {
      method: 'DELETE',
        body: JSON.stringify({ item_id: bookId }),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });
    await thunkAPI.dispatch(removeBook(bookId));
    return response.data;
  }
);
```

```
export const removeBook = (bookId) => ({
  type: REMOVE,
  bookId,
});
```

```
const bookReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    ...

    case REMOVE: 
      return state.filter(
        (book) => book.item_id !== action.bookId // <-- access book id
      );

    ...
  }
};
```

#### Check for successful response when removing book

The the `fetch` response `ok`* property to ensure the DELETE request was actually successful.

Example:

```
export const deleteBooks = createAsyncThunk(
  REMOVE,
  async (bookId, thunkAPI) => {
    const response = await fetch(`${BOOK_URL}/${bookId}`,  {
      method: 'DELETE',
        body: JSON.stringify({ item_id: bookId }),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });
    
    if (response.ok) {
      thunkAPI.dispatch(removeBook(bookId));
    }
    return response.data;
  }
);
```

****Note:** `response.ok` is pretty standard but consult the API documentation if success/failure is expressed differently.*